# How can I parse JSON file in App Inventor?

Tags: json, app-inventor

I want to ask about how can I parse `JSON` file in APP INVENTOR.

I'm just following the code from this site : [imagnity](https://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/web-component-json-response-on-app-inventor/)

But there always give me `No Result on Google`, maybe I put a wrong `startTag` or something.

Here is my `block`:

[image: myblock]

And here is my `JSON`:

[image: myjson]

sorry for sensor content in `JSON`, because there are some reasons haha.

FYI: the response code is `200`

Comment: you might want to do a search in the App Inventor community like this https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/search?q=parse%20json, additionally you might also want to do a search in the Kodular community here https://community.kodular.io/search?q=parse%20JSON. An extension might help to simplify this... see the extensions directory here https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php and search for JSON extensions...

Comment: Thank you Taifun,  I will try to search there.